# Two basic questions about topological group theory

Tags: topological-groups

For a topological group, I'd like to know whether

1.there exist a topological group G which is a Hausdorff space but does not satisfies the first countable axiom or

2.there exist a topological group G which is not a Hausdorff space and does not satisfies the first countable axiom.

I really find it difficult for me. Help me please. I can't work it out so far.

Please give me two examples about them. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

1. The product of uncountably many discrete groups of order two is a compact Hausdorff topological group which is not first countable.
2. To get a topological group which is neither Hausdorff nor first countable, take the product of any non-first-countable topological group (such as the one in the previous example) with any non-Hausdorff topological group (such as a group of order two with the "indiscrete" topology).

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have a  little/bit of confused about "1.The product of uncountably many discrete groups of order two is a compact Hausdorff topological group which is not first countable." Why it's not the first countable? Please show me about it.

Comment: It's not first countable because, if you form the intersection of countably many basic neighborhoods of $0$, you don't get $\{0\}$. Alternatively, if you take the product of $2^{\aleph_0}$ copies of $\{0,1\}$, you get a separable Hausdorff space with $\gt2^{\aleph_0}$ points; it can't be first countable, because a first countable separable Hausdorff space has $\le2^{\aleph_0}$ points.

Comment: Ah ha, I have known about that. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have received a satisfactory answer to your question, you may wish to consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.